# How To Calculate Exact 99.9th Percentile in Splunk

Tags: splunk, percentile, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

Does anyone know how to exactly calculate the 99.9th percentile in Splunk?

I have tried a variety of methods as below, such as exactperc (but this only takes integer percentiles) and perc (but this approximates the result heavily).

```
base | stats exactperc99(latency) as "99th Percentile", p99.9(latency) as "99.9th Percentile"
```

Thanks,
James

Comment: What version of Splunk? exactperc99.9 works in 6.6 for me.

Comment: Hi, my Splunk version is 6.5.1.

Comment: using "base | stats exactperc99(latency), perc99.9(latency), exactperc99.9(latency)" gives the output as "exactperc99(latency) = 1.332, perc99.9(latency) =10.000, exactperc99.9(latency) = 17.686.

Comment: The figure for exactperc99 seems correct, however perc99.9 and exactperc99.9 are worryingly large and significantly different to each other.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Splunk documentation](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/latest/SearchReference/Aggregatefunctions#perc.3CX.3E.28Y.29):

> There are three different percentile functions:
>
> perc<X>(Y) (or the abbreviation p<X>(Y)) upperperc<X>(Y)
> exactperc<X>(Y) Returns the X-th percentile value of the numeric field
> Y. Valid values of X are floating point numbers from 1 to 99, such as
> 99.95.
>
> Use the perc<X>(Y) function to calculate an approximate threshold,
> such that of the values in field Y, X percent fall below the
> threshold.
>
> The perc and upperperc functions give approximate values for the
> integer percentile requested. The approximation algorithm that is
> used, which is based on dynamic compression of a radix tree, provides
> a strict bound of the actual value for any percentile. The perc
> function returns a single number that represents the lower end of that
> range. The upperperc function gives the approximate upper bound. The
> exactperc function provides the exact value, but will be very
> expensive for high cardinality fields. The exactperc function could
> consume a large amount of memory in the search head.
>
> Processes field values as strings.

Examples:

```
 p99.999(response_ms)
 p99(bytes_received)
 p50(salary) # median
```